# How to run http web service request from pl/sql package

Tags: oracle, web, service, plsql, package

I have developed a new procedure to call web service but its showing Oracle adaptor error when I run it. Could you please guide me how can I resolve this error? Is teher something wrong below code?

```
/* Formatted on 17/07/2014 16:49:02 (QP5 v5.185.11230.41888) */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.xx_web_id
IS
l_http_request    UTL_HTTP.req;
l_http_response   UTL_HTTP.resp;
l_response_text   VARCHAR2 (10000);
BEGIN
-- preparing request
l_http_request :=
  UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('https://freegeoip.net/xml/82.39.109.147',
                          'POST',
                          'HTTP/1.1');

l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (l_http_request);

UTL_HTTP.read_text (l_http_response, l_response_text);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_response_text);

UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
EXCEPTION
WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body
THEN
  UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
END;
```

Comment: If you are using Oracle 11g or later, it is likely that you are held back by the absence of an ACL (Access Control List).  It grants/denies network traffic outgoing and incoming from the database server based on the exceptions the DBA or administrator defines.  

It is made by running procedure calls with parameters identifying the user accounts, the source and destination port/ip-address ranges etc.

Think carefully if you are attempting to send out (or receive) requests over the Internet.  Read up on the security suggestions for ACL assigned privileges.

Comment: And the details of the error are ?

Comment: Please provide the error details. You might have to provide the correct headers. Check the answer in my post. After a couple of days, i got the following answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838138/how-to-sent-a-post-request-as-json-in-plsql

Answer (score 1):

First you should configure ACL ;

```
BEGIN
dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(acl => 'pkg.xml',
                                description => 'Normal Access',
                                principal => 'CONNECT',
                                is_grant => TRUE,
                                privilege => 'connect',
                                start_date => NULL,
                                end_date => NULL);
    END;
    /

    BEGIN
    dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege(acl => 'utlpkg.xml',
                                   principal => 'XXXX', --- user name
                                   is_grant => TRUE,
                                   privilege => 'connect',
                                   start_date => NULL,
                                   end_date => NULL);
      END;
      /


   BEGIN
      dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(acl => 'pkg.xml',
                                host => 'HOST ADDRESS',--  Web Server URL
                                lower_port => 7222, -- Web  Server PORTs
                                upper_port => 7222);
    END;
   /
```

Then you should create procedure which will be called web service. Sample that i used you may find in below;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE web_service_call()
AS

l_http_request     UTL_HTTP.req;
l_http_response    UTL_HTTP.resp;
l_buffer_size      NUMBER (10)      := 512;
l_line_size        NUMBER (10)      := 50;
l_lines_count      NUMBER (10)      := 20;
l_clob_request   CLOB;
l_line             VARCHAR2 (32767);
l_substring_msg    VARCHAR2 (32767);
l_raw_data         RAW (512);
l_clob_response    CLOB;
l_host_name        VARCHAR2 (128)   := 'get.bla.bla';
l_port             VARCHAR2 (128)   := '7222'; 
req_length binary_integer;
bufferY   varchar(2000);
amount  pls_integer:=2000;
offset  pls_integer:=1;

BEGIN

  l_clob_request := 'xml'; 
  l_http_request :=
     UTL_HTTP.begin_request (url               =>    'http://'
                                                  || l_host_name
                                                  || ':'
                                                  || l_port
                                                  || '/Something/GetSomething',
                             method            => 'POST',
                             http_version      => 'HTTP/1.1'
                            );
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request,
                       'Host',
                       l_host_name || ':' || l_port
                      );
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request, 'Connection', 'close');
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-9'); 
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request, 'SOAPAction', '"sayHello"');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request,
                       'Content-Length',
                       LENGTH (l_clob_request)
                      );   

        req_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength (l_clob_request);
        offset :=1;
        bufferY :=null;
        amount:=2000;

  WHILE (offset < req_length)
   LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.read (l_clob_request,
                     amount,
                     offset,
                     bufferY);
      UTL_HTTP.write_text (l_http_request, bufferY);
      offset := offset + amount;

   END LOOP;  
      l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (l_http_request); 
      l_clob_response :=null;
      BEGIN

         <<response_loop>>
         LOOP
            UTL_HTTP.read_raw (l_http_response, l_raw_data, l_buffer_size);
            l_clob_response :=
                     l_clob_response || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (l_raw_data);
         END LOOP response_loop;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body
         THEN
            UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
      END; 

  IF l_http_request.private_hndl IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     UTL_HTTP.end_request (l_http_request);
  END IF;

  IF l_http_response.private_hndl IS NOT NULL
  THEN
     UTL_HTTP.end_response (l_http_response);
  END IF; 
END;
 /
```