# How the JWT validation works in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to access a REST web service using PLSQL, and basic authentication works great, however the service provider says basic authentication is not safe and they only offer token-based authentication.

I looked at the AS_CRYPTO package, but it uses some algorithms and public and private keys, whereas the service provider says they do not use keys and will only issue a token that will be valid for 15 minutes, and I can keep sending the token back to authenticate for as many API calls as I want.

My request to you is that you assist me in understanding how token-based authentication would function in PLSQL. Do I really need them to tell me the algorithm they used and if keys are really needed as it seems to be the case with AS_CRPTO package.

We do not use Apex so advise if there are other options available to make it work using PLSQL.

Comment: Your service provider should be providing an authentication API to to return a token to use for subsequent API calls.

Comment: Oh my god! Why would you do REST requests from inside Oracle DB 

Comment: So from where I do it?

Comment: you still have not explained how your vendor provides you a token.  That is not something you generate. but the vendor does through some API.

Comment: There is no reason you can't do an HTTP call to an endpoint from the database.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - Yes, the vendor gave us a API to use and when we call it gives us token.

Comment: OK, then what is your specific question?  If they gave you an API to return a token, then what is stopping you from using it?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I can not understand how to do it using UTL_HTTP. It would be amazing if you can show me some example for using it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838138/how-to-sent-a-post-request-as-json-in-plsql

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like OAuth2 authentication. There is plenty of information of that on the internet, it's the most widely used standard. It is a 2-step process. No encryption should be needed (that should be done by your protocol - https)

This is the high level process. Much smarter people might be able to give you a more detailed explanation.

Step 1: Get the bearer token. The provider should give you an url, and a set of credentials. The bearer token is sent back as payload. It is just a long string. Call that url to obtain the token

Step 2: Invoke the actual rest service and pass the bearer token in the header to authenticate.

I'd google "pl/sql get bearer token" for examples.

Comment: I tried but there are no examples on this topic.