# invoking webservice from inside pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-24247

I have the user name under ACl and acl has been assigned to host.
but I am getting error http_req filed on trying to connact

ACL has been assigned to host

```
SELECT * FROM dba_network_acls;
1   *.mer.com           /sys/acls/fine_grain_access_http.xml         968743177C0D29D9E040A8C02F1C05F0
```

user has been added to ACL with connect and resolve prov

```
SELECT * FROM dba_network_acl_privileges where principal=’SCOTT’
ACL                                  ACLID                                  PRINCIPAL   PRIVILEGE   IS_GRANT    INVERT  
1   /sys/acls/fine_grain_access_http.xml    968743177C0D29D9E040A8C02F1C05F0        PRASHANT-MISHRA connect         true        false       
2   /sys/acls/fine_grain_access_http.xml    968743177C0D29D9E040A8C02F1C05F0        PRASHANT-MISHRA resolve     true        false
```

below  is the code section I am rying to execute

```
DECLARE
req UTL_HTTP.req;
resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
v_URL VARCHAR2(2000);
VALUE VARCHAR2(32767);
Rpt_id NUMBER:=38660;
part1 VARCHAR2(200);
part2 VARCHAR2(100);
part3 VARCHAR2(100);
username VARCHAR2(100):='PRASHANT-MISHRA';
pass VARCHAR2(100):='Summer@2015';
BEGIN
part1:='http://jira.mer.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/';
part2:='/SearchRequest-38660tempMax=3000&';
part3:='field=key';
v_URL:=part1||part2||Rpt_id||part3;

req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(v_URL,'GET','HTTP/1.1');

UTL_HTTP.set_authentication(req, username, pass);
UTL_HTTP.set_header (req,'Content-Type','application/xml; charset=utf-8');
/*UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, ‘User-Agent’, ‘Mozilla/4.0′);*/
resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(req);
LOOP
UTL_HTTP.read_line(resp, value, TRUE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(value);
END LOOP;
UTL_HTTP.end_response(resp);
END;
```

Error:

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
>    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
>    ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
>    ORA-06512: at line 19

Comment: Did you give grant for user.  `grant execute on utl_http to XXXXX` , and here is the question that i answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808240/how-to-run-http-web-service-request-from-pl-sql-package/29012077#29012077

Answer (score 1):

I forgot committing changes after running add_priv to add priv for user to ACL.